# Match multiple instances of the same pattern in a multiline string

Tags: r, stringr

Using stringr, how can I match at least two repetitions of the same word (e.g., ontime) in a text:

```
2008-07-01 : :cancelled
2005-11-01 : :postponed
2005-06-28 : :ontime
 :Train_528 :cancelled
 :Train_528 :postponed
 :Train_528 :ontime
```

In this example, I want to highlight all rows that have at least two instances of the string 'ontime'.

If the string was this:

```
2008-07-01 : :cancelled
2005-11-01 : :postponed
2005-06-28 : :ontime
```

It wouldn't match this row.

I have tried this code but it wasn't successful:

```
str_detect(column, "(ontime){2,}"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df = tibble(
    string = c("2008-07-01 : :cancelled
2005-11-01 : :postponed
2005-06-28 : :ontime
 :Train_528 :cancelled
 :Train_528 :postponed
 :Train_528 :ontime", "2008-07-01 : :cancelled
2005-11-01 : :postponed
2005-06-28 : :ontime")
)

mutate(df, match = str_detect(string, "(?s)ontime.*ontime"))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  string                                                                   match
  <chr>                                                                    <lgl>
1 "2008-07-01 : :cancelled\n2005-11-01 : :postponed\n2005-06-28 : :ontime… TRUE 
2 "2008-07-01 : :cancelled\n2005-11-01 : :postponed\n2005-06-28 : :ontime" FALSE
```

The pattern `(?s)ontime.*ontime` matches "ontime", followed by anything, any number of times, and then another "ontime". Usually, periods don't match newlines, so we add the `(?s)` flag to change that.